# What development stack to use?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, frameworks

I am planning to build a website and after that, to create an app with the access to the same database and the same functions as the website. So I heard, that with Ionic, I could save my time and develop a hybrid application, so I do not have to do the same work twice. The website should be a portal, which is a mix of a social network and an online shop.

What do you think, is it a good idea to use NodeJs for the Back-End for that?

So as I think my development stack would look this way:
Ionic2 with AngularJS2, NodeJS for Back-End and MySQL for storing data.

Can you say, how can I improve my development stack? Are there some things, which are bad compatible, or everything seems to be ok?

Kind regards,

Andrej

Comment: you should choose development stack on the basis of requirement rather than popular stack.  There are number of stack/platform/environment provide cross platform development like ionic, meteor, react-native, etc. You should compare and choose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use web services like restful web services for accessing database from website and mobile application.